# AngularJS: How to correctly pass in moment.js dependency?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I have an `app.js`, where I've declared my app variable/module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularMoment']);
```

Then I'm got my controller passing in the reference along with others and trying to make a `moment()` call:

```
myApp.controller('myComtroller', ['$scope', 'moment', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, moment) {
    var now = moment();
    console.log(now);
}]);
```

I get an error in my console spitting this out:

> TypeError: moment is not a function

I don't understand why it's doing this.

Towards the end of my body, I have this as my references:

```
<script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
```

In that order. (the controller gets executed later, part of the section scripts for that view)

I installed `moment.js` through downloading it from here: http://momentjs.com/docs/

But I installed the `angular-moment` dependency through `bower`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to move moment.js and angular-moment.min.js before app.js

Comment: @123456789 I just tried that

Comment: @VolcovMeter is it working now?

Comment: @Sajeetharan no, it's not working.

Comment: @VolcovMeter check the answer

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the angular-moment js library, but the moment.js library does not have an angular provider to inject moment into your controller. It's simply a global function that you can call. So remove `moment` from the function declaration and [inline array annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for the dependency injection. Also be sure that your inline array annotation matches your function declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing some dependencies in your dependency annotation.

Try:

```
myApp.controller('myComtroller', [
         '$scope','$http', '$timeout', 'moment', 
function ($scope , $http ,  $timeout,   moment) {
    var now = moment();
    console.log(now);
}]);
```

Also, I would recommend to use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to automatically handle DI annotations.

Answer (score 0):

look at `angular-momentjs.js` https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdi2290/angular-momentjs/master/angular-momentjs.js

Load the script angular-momentjs.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./angular-momentjs.js"></script>
```

Inject dependencies angular-momentjs in app module, and $moment in controller

```
let app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular-momentjs']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $moment) {
   let nowISO = $moment().toISOString();
   console.log(nowISO);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass depdencies in the correct order,

```
myApp.controller('myComtroller', [
         '$scope','$http', '$timeout', 'moment', 
function ($scope , $http ,  $timeout,   moment) {
    var now = moment();
    console.log(now);
}]);
```

You do not need to pass moment service as a dependency, you can just do the below,

```
myapp.controller("myComtroller", function($scope) {
$scope.date = moment();       
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/m1opszxx/28/)**

Comment: @VolcovMeter some one i think without a reason. did it work?

Comment: @VolcovMeter you dont have to pass moment